# What are the are these parts called in my tower PC case?

Tags: hard-drive, case, case-mods

I want to put another hard drive in my Cooler Master case, but it came with only two hard drive screws that are holding it in the hard drive bay as shown in the picture. What are they exactly called so I can search online if they are still available?

[image]

Comment: what is your cases model number?  that should help narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

### Internal Hard Drive Components

These are the components you need to fit an HDD/SSD into your Cooler Master case.

You already have the cage, so look for the other components you need.
In your image, the existing HDD is on a [mounting bracket](https://www.cmstore.eu/spare-parts/trooper-stryker-hdd-bracket/). You need a compatible one of those.

[image]

- <s>Hard Drive Cage</s>
- Hard Drive [Tray](http://www.coolermaster.com/case/case-accessories/ssd-tray/)
- Hard Drive [Brackets](https://www.cmstore.eu/spare-parts/trooper-stryker-hdd-bracket/)
- Hard Drive [Rails](https://www.cmstore.eu/spare-parts/hdd-rails-new/)

Answer (score 1):

Your photo doesn't appear to contain a hard drive cage. You've provided the manufacturer name, so I used "cooler master hard drive locks" which returned a number of useful links. It appears that Cooler Master has different versions for the different model numbers.

There's a number of videos showing how to remove and install the locks, but your question is what they are called.

I would suggest to use your model number along with the above search terms, to reduce the number of false links on the journey to find the correct model.

I would have provided at least one link but the model variations are quite numerous.